# Amazon connect: can on choose area code and can one host more than one free instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I find it troublesome to get "tech support", as that should come along with a $29 bill. I only have two simple questions to ask:

1. Can one choose the "area code" for phone numbers (a quick [search](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation-guide&searchQuery=area%20code&x=0&y=0&this_doc_product=Amazon%20Connect&this_doc_guide=User%20Guide&doc_locale=en_us#facet_doc_product=Amazon%20Connect&facet_doc_guide=User%20Guide) on the Documentation does not yield any mentioning)
2. Can one run multiple *free* instances of Amazon connect, each occupying a unique phone number?

#### Short answer to Q1 and Q2

1. According to the kind reply, one can pick area code freely.
2. Yet, Amazon Connect mimics the model of a call center. Thus, incoming calls shall arrive at a single number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, when you claim a number you can specify an area code (assuming we are talking about US area codes)

Select “Phone Numbers” from the Routing menu
[image: routing menu]

Choose “claim a number”

Enter a prefix (area code) to filter the list of available numbers with a specific area code.
[image: prefix emample]

NOTE: you may not get results for every area code. If you are looking for a new number in a specific area code that does not show results, you would need to open a support ticket to request a number in that area code.

2. You can one have one number for free per account, when you add the number to the second instance you will be charged the daily rate for the number.

Comment: thank you for clarifying the pricing. Yet, for the Area Code: I don't see an option to specify "which area-code I would like". Instead, there are no more than 10 numbers that I can choose from. Would this "choose your area code" be a hidden feature? Thx!

Comment: I have updated the answer with more specifics. In the initial wizard you don’t have the option to specify a prefix, you have to do this from the phone numbers menu option.

Comment: thank you for clarifying! I've submitted a support ticket to request a phone number with area-code that I would need. (In my case, it is pretty *selective* in that I am targeting one specific region.) Also, thank you for clarifying the pricing!